# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) with a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have this issue when creating a code with Python. I pass a list of tuples but when unpacking it and then using the map function and then using a list. I get this Error:

**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

Any idea how to overcome this? I can't find a suitable answer yet related to a list of tuples :-(

Here is the code

```
stock_markets = [('AAPL','200'),('MSFT','780'),('ORCL','650'),('CISC','350')]

def analyze_stocks(stock_markets):
    current_max = 0
    stock_name = ''

    for company,price in stock_markets:
        if int(price) > current_max:
            current_max = int(price)
            stock_name = company
        else:
            pass

    return (stock_name, current_max)

list(map(analyze_stocks,stock_markets))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already iterating over your list with `map`. Your for loop inside the analyze function is not needed (since you're passing your stocks one by one already with `map`) and it is the source of error. Correct version should be something like this:

```py
stock_markets = [('AAPL','200'),('MSFT','780'),('ORCL','650'),('CISC','350')]

def analyze_stocks(stock_markets):
    current_max = 0
    stock_name = ''

    company, price = stock_markets
    if int(price) > current_max:
        current_max = int(price)
        stock_name = company

    return (stock_name, current_max)

list(map(analyze_stocks,stock_markets))
```

Comment: Thank you bkakilli

The only concern is the answer will output the same list and we want to only output the element with the max value ('MSFT','780') from the list.

```
[('AAPL', 200), ('MSFT', 780), ('ORCL', 650), ('CISC', 350)]
```

Comment: Then you don't really need a `map` there I think. I would just iterate over the stocks with a for loop without using `map` in the code.